# how to perform a slide view on a button click

Tags: ios

in my main view controller the button action is

```
-(IBAction)ChangeImage
        {

        UIImage *guns = [UIImage imageNamed:@"guns.png"]; // load our image resource
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:guns];

            NSLog(@"kaam hua..??");
            [self.view addSubview:imageView];

            [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                                toView:imageView
                              duration:3.0f

             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            completion:nil];

                                NSLog(@"hfhjlkhbjhdfcvkbjnlkhgj");
     }
```

1. i want to view the animation in slide view
2. is there any method to do this
3. can i chnage the UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve to another one to show slide view

Comment: Elobrate your requirement then some one can helps you.@Amit205

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn** in animation option,

Try this,

```
CGRect or=self.view.frame;

CGRect basketTopFrame = self.view.frame;
basketTopFrame.origin.x =  basketTopFrame.size.width;

self.view.frame = basketTopFrame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                          [self.view addSubview:imageView];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

Comment: i have alrready slide this but i want sliding just we slide in our mobile

Comment: Use pagination option enabled it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234875/programmatically-scroll-a-uiscrollview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185010/navigate-to-specific-page-in-scrollview-with-paging-programatically