# Jump to a certain page in a scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view set up with paging. How would i programmatically jump to a specific page in the scroll view. The content size is `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 568);`. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530259/uiscrollview-to-jump-particular-page?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [– setContentOffset:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a). You would do your own math to decide what a "page" is but you would probably base it off the bounds of the scroll view.