# How do I force a scroll view to go to next page?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view with paging enabled, and I want it to go to the next page when a button is pressed. Is this possible? Is there a method to do so?

Comment: You need to set the content offset, there is no **go to next page method** in UIScrollView `- (void)setContentOffset:animated:`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change page on UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926810/change-page-on-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to some point in a scroll view with

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

To do slideshows with UIScrollView, you arrange all images in the scroll view, set up a repeated timer, then -setContentOffset:animated: when the timer fires.

But a more efficient approach is to use 2 image views and swap them using transitions or simply switching places when the timer fires. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631170/iphone-image-slideshow)  for details.

**OR**

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;

frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageNumberYouWantToGoTo;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```